# All checkbox in listview is not getting visible from invisible state when button is clicked from Mainactivity

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I am new to android. I am struggling with the checkbox in listview. By default I made my checkbox in listview to be in INVISIBLE mode when the button is clicked from MainActivity. I want to all checkbox in listview to be in VISIBLE mode but when I am clicking the button check box is VISIBLE in only one list row in all other rows. Still the check box is in INVISIBLE mode.

**FavouriteListAdapter**

```
public class FavouriteListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
ArrayList<FavouritesArray> mArrFavourites;
ViewHolder viewHolder;
String favId;

//Make checkbox to visible in all rows in listview
public void setcheckbox() {
    viewHolder.favCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView favName;
    public TextView favUrl;
    public TextView favAddress;
    public CheckBox favCheckbox;
}

public FavouriteListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FavouritesArray> lArrFavourites) {
    mContext = context;
    mArrFavourites = lArrFavourites;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (mArrFavourites == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return mArrFavourites.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.favouritelistadapter, parent, false);
        viewHolder.favName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_name);
        viewHolder.favUrl = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_url);
        viewHolder.favAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_address);
        viewHolder.favCheckbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_checkbox);
        viewHolder.favCheckbox .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final FavouritesArray chooseService = mArrFavourites.get(position);
        viewHolder.favName.setText(chooseService.getFavouritename());
        viewHolder.favAddress.setText(chooseService.getFavouritelocation());

    viewHolder.favCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                favId = chooseService.getFavouritename();
                ((MainActivity) mContext).check(favId);
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}}
```

Comment: Am struct here need some help please give me some idea

Answer (score 0):

I think you need boolean varibale **showCheckBox** and check it state in method **getView**.
Look at this sample:

```
private boolean showCheckBox = false;

public void showChecBox(boolean show) {
    showCheckBox = show;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.favouritelistadapter, parent, false);
        viewHolder.favName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_name);
        viewHolder.favUrl = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_url);
        viewHolder.favAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_address);
        viewHolder.favCheckbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_checkbox);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final FavouritesArray chooseService = mArrFavourites.get(position);
    viewHolder.favName.setText(chooseService.getFavouritename());
    viewHolder.favAddress.setText(chooseService.getFavouritelocation());
    int checkBoxVisibility = showCheckBox : View.VISIBLE ? View.INVISIBLE;
    viewHolder.favCheckbox.setVisibility(checkBoxVisibility);

    viewHolder.favCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                favId = chooseService.getFavouritename();
                ((MainActivity) mContext).check(favId);
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander its working , in similar way please tell me how to make all check box to be in invisibe mode again

Comment: you should call **showChecBox(false)** and after it **notifyDataSetChanged()**. This methods are called from click listener of your button

Answer (score 0):

when a button is clicked in activity you need to call `adapter.showCheckBoxes(true)` of your adapter. then set a field to `showCheckBoxes=true;` in that function and also refresh the list using `notifyDataSetChanged()` which will cause the `getView` method to be called for all the rows.
In `getView` check if showCheckBoxes is true or not and show check boxes accordingly.

```
    public class FavouriteListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
ArrayList<FavouritesArray> mArrFavourites;
ViewHolder viewHolder;
String favId;
boolean showCheckBoxes = false;
//Make checkbox to visible in all rows in listview
public void setcheckbox() {
    viewHolder.favCheckbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView favName;
    public TextView favUrl;
    public TextView favAddress;
    public CheckBox favCheckbox;
}

public FavouriteListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FavouritesArray> lArrFavourites) {
    mContext = context;
    mArrFavourites = lArrFavourites;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (mArrFavourites == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return mArrFavourites.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.favouritelistadapter, parent, false);
        viewHolder.favName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_name);
        viewHolder.favUrl = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_url);
        viewHolder.favAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_address);
        viewHolder.favCheckbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_checkbox);
        viewHolder.favCheckbox .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final FavouritesArray chooseService = mArrFavourites.get(position);
        viewHolder.favName.setText(chooseService.getFavouritename());
        viewHolder.favAddress.setText(chooseService.getFavouritelocation());
if(showCheckBoxes){
viewHolder.favCheckbox .setVisibility(VISIBLE);
}else{
viewHolder.favCheckbox .setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
}
    viewHolder.favCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                favId = chooseService.getFavouritename();
                ((MainActivity) mContext).check(favId);
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}}

public void showCheckBoxes(boolean showCheckBoxes){
this.showCheckBoxes=showCheckBoxes;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

in your button click function:

```
void onClick(View v){
    mAdapter.showCheckBoxes(true);
}
```